# How to replace @ sign in JavaScript on a Razor page?

Tags: javascript, razor

```
 var str= 'abcd@1';
 var rplc=str.replace("@", "_");
```

If I try this in a cshtml mvc page, the @ sign is considered to be razor syntax, and I get an error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The Razor parser considers `@` to be Razor syntax. Try with `@@` to escape the `@`.

Comment: I've made an edit to the question actually to not assume javascript is the culprit.